# How to write to a seperate html file in plain browser javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, filesystems

I know that you can write to the current HTML document, but I want to write to another html file.
For example:
I have 2 files, one is `index.html`, and the other is `completedsurvey.html`
I want to write something to the completedsurvey.html from my index.html file. Is there a way
to do this that is supported in most browsers?

Comment: Why do you need two files? You can replace the content of the current page.

Comment: Are you talking about data, like a filled in form?

Comment: Please note that when people talk about the document or DOM in JavaScript, they don’t mean the actual html file

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, I want to transfer data from a filled in form to another document.

Comment: Here is what I understand that you need: You fill data from in a form on index.html, and after processing it, you want to show users what they filled on completedsurvey.html?

Comment: @Jack yep, exactly

Comment: So I guess there can be two ways: 
1.You either keep the data temp in local storage and retrieve it on page load of completesurvey.html
2. if server api is involved,then  send back  required data in the response from server to Client on  success.

Comment: @Jack Could you (if you can) give an example of 1.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the first solution:
Assuming you'd want to display "username" and "summary" on successful submission of the form.
This isn't an exact solution, just something you can use to get the concept.

index.html

```
    <form>
    <input type='text' id="username">
    <input type='text' id="summary">
    <button type="button" id="process-form">
    </form>
    
    <script>
       document.getElementById('process-form').addEventListener('click', (eve)=>{
       
    
          var uname = document.getElementById('username');
          var summ = document.getElementById('summary');
          localStorage.setItem('uname', uname);//saving the data in local storage
          localStorage.setItem('summ', summ);
//redirect to next page...
       });
    </script>
```

surveycomplete.html

```
<!doctype>
.
.
<div> 
<h1 id="name"> </h1>
<p id='summary'> </p>
</div>
<script>
  var uname = localStorage.getItem('uname');//retrieving from local storage
  var summ = localStorage.getItem('summ');
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = uname;//fill the fields with data 
  .
  .
</script>
```

Further Links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage